# How can I clean out an older deployment on my App Service in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a new version of my web app and after a new deployment from a new Bitbucket repo the old version is still served. I've deleted the App Service and then created it again, but still the old stuff is served. Everything I've tried results in a successful deployment of the new code, but when I browse the site, the old version is served. To get rid of the old code can I go to the console and just delete everything in site/wwwroot? Is there a git repo in Azure I can initialize?

Comment: How did you deploy? Did you use the kudu console to verify that the deployed files were current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [continuous deployment for your Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment) app. AFAIK, for basic web site deployment, azure would clone your Bitbucket repo to `D:\home\site\repository`, then restore packages or compile your project, then deploy your project to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.

As David commented that you could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or ftp tool (e.g. [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)) to check your files under `site\wwwroot` and `site\repository`, and compare with your Bitbucket repo to make sure your source code has been synced into `site\repository`.

Also, you could try to delete `site\wwwroot` and `site\repository` via KUDU, then Disconnect and set your continuous deployment again on Azure portal to isolate this issue.

Comment: If I recall, continuous deployment also requires you to select a branch. Just to add this to the checklist, perhaps ensure that your continuous deployment is pulling from the same branch you are pushing commits to?

Comment: @Bruce Thanks for your answer, which teaches me about the plumbing of my deployment. Yes, I am using continuous deployment. However, I won't need to do any of that checking now, since the problem has gone away by itself. The correct bits are served now. Strange! Another strange thing about this problem is that while it existed, I had different results using different URLs. When I used the URL shown on the dashboard, or when I clicked the Browse button, I got the old code. But if i prepended the URL with https instead of http, then I got the correct new code. Strange again!

Comment: P.S. In thinking about the different result when switching the two protocol prefixes, I believe it was a cache problem. Any opinion?

Comment: It may be a cache issue. Have you tried to clear the cache or browser in private mode to check this issue?